# Display content with Taxonomy on User and Content matching

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I've got a specific content type.  One field is a term reference field called "blog subject" in which a content author tags the node.

Ok.  Moving on to the end user.  I added the same term reference field to user account settings in which a user can select certain terms that they're interested in.

I would like to create a view in which the contextual filter is the user.  By going to www.whatever.com/blogs/12, I can see content that matches the users selected interests.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view showing users, and use a contextual filter on `User:UID`, and set 'Provide default value' the the 'Currently logged in user'.

You then should create two Relationships. The first on `User:blog_subject` will relate the user to the taxonomy terms. The second, using the first, will be on `Taxonomy Term: Content using Blog Subject` which will then relate the term to the content. Both relationships should be '*Required*'.

Once the relationships  are in place, delete the '*User Name*' field that is a default for the type of view you created, and add the `Content:Title` field displayed as a link to content. Add filters like `Content:Published` to eliminate un-published content and a sort by, for example, `Content:Post Date (desc)`. All of these fields will be using the relationships. Make sure you delete all the `User:...` filters and sorts.

With multiple terms possible, this may create duplicate rows. There are two approaches you can use. The simplest is to go to *Advanced > Other* and configure the *Query Settings* to '*Distinct*'. This might work. The other is to list the term and Set the view to Group By the term. That way you will get a list of pages that conform to each subject. If a page appears multiple times, it will do so under separate subject lists.

This should show a list of content matching the interests of the current user.

Comment: Thanks...was missing one of the relationships.  Perfect.  Danke!

Comment: I was getting duplicates as mentioned, 'Distinct' wasn't working for me and I didnt want to have my content grouped together in the view. 

I solved this with Aggregation. Enable aggregation in Advanced > use aggregation. Select aggregation settings on a unique field (in my case title) > aggregation type "group results together" > group column "value" > apply.