# Display Content with Taxonomy on User and content matching with Multiple Vocabularies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I am trying to create a view to show content that is tagged with taxonomy terms from the users profile (*each vocabulary has its own field in the users profile where the user can select via check boxes what they are interested in.*)

I read and watched multiple tutorials and articles on this, and the closest I can get is described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74475/display-content-with-taxonomy-on-user-and-content-matching) by Triskelion:

> create a user view, add relationships: **Content: Tags (my Vocab)** and **Taxonomy term: Content with term** with a contextual filter on the **User:UID**, then display the **content:title**. This works perfectly given one vocabulary, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work correctly with multiple vocabs.

I added multiples of the above relationships for each of the vocabs, and display multiple **content:titles** with each relationship, but the problem is that *each row in the view will contain only one different title. Aggregation and Querey distinct settings don't seem to help!!*

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I know there is a solution to scrap my multiple vocabularies and just put all terms into one but this is not really desirable, as id lose the structure of my taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you are trying to eliminate duplicates from your view.
Display only one title by content.

When I'm in a case when even Aggregation or Query Distinct settings don't seem to work (most of the time this is caused because the query left/inner joins),  I use a small script that does the trick to do an easy group by using the query comment field. In your case you could group by node.id

```
/**
 *  Found this trick on theoleschool.com.
 *  
 *  Description: Allows the view developer to specify the query
 *  group by action in the query comments. Great way to force the
 *  removal of duplicates.
 *  
 *  Just go into your query comments and type in "groupby:" with
 *  that colon followed by the field you want to group by.
 * 
 *  Examples...
 *  groupby:node.nid
 *  groupby:file_managed_file_usage.fid
 * 
 *  Ref-Comment: http://theoleschool.com/comment/496#comment-496
 *  Ref-Article: http://theoleschool.com/blog/using-hookviewsalter-add-group-statement
 */
function mymodule_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('views')) {
    static $count;
    $view =& $query->getMetaData('view');

    if (strstr($groupby = $view->query->options['query_comment'], 'groupby')) {
      list($action, $field) = explode(':', $groupby);

      if (strlen($field) > 0) {
        $query->groupBy($field);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I took the easy way out and reduced my taxonomy to one single vocabulary which solved the issue. Hopefully your response can help someone else out with the same issue though!